# How can I implement IGNORE NULLS in window functions such as FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

How can I implement IGNORE NULLS in window functions such as FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE in MySQL?

For example, let's say we have a very simple table called sales.

| SaleID | CustomerID | SaleRegion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | CITY A |
| 2 | 10 | NULL |
| 3 | 10 | NULL |
| 4 | 7 | CITY A |
| 5 | 10 | CITY B |
| 6 | 10 | CITY C |

How can I get the first value of sale region partitioned by customer id?

Expected (Desired) Output:

| CUSTOMERID | FIRST_VALUE(SALEREGION) |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | CITY A |
| 7 | CITY A |
| 10 | CITY B |
| 10 | CITY B |
| 10 | CITY B |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to ignore nulls completely, you can always use an inner query to remove nulls before passing the values to window function or any expression.

In the given example;

```
SELECT CustomerID
    ,FIRST_VALUE(SaleRegion) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID) as SaleRegion
FROM (SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE SaleRegion IS NOT NULL) as new_table
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ORDER BY `SaleRegion` DESC in the window function.

If one customer has multiple regions, you need to refine the Order by

```
CREATE TABLE customers
    (`aleID` int, `CustomerID` int, `SaleRegion` varchar(6))
;
    
INSERT INTO customers
    (`aleID`, `CustomerID`, `SaleRegion`)
VALUES
    (1, 7, 'CITY A'),
    (2, 10, NULL),
    (3, 10, NULL),
    (4, 7, 'CITY A'),
    (5, 10, 'CITY B')
;
```

```
SELECT
`CustomerID`, FIRST_VALUE(`SaleRegion`) OVER( PARTITION BY `CustomerID` ORDER BY `SaleRegion` DESC
  )  as SaleRegion
  FROM customers
```

| CustomerID | SaleRegion |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | CITY A |
| 7 | CITY A |
| 10 | CITY B |
| 10 | CITY B |
| 10 | CITY B |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/znEuumur)

Comment: Hi thank you for responding. What if customer id = 10 has multiple cities? If I use DESC it will push down the null values but consequentially reorder the sale region. Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: I've edited the question to include multiple cities to clarify the question.

Comment: Yes, but you need to accept this answer and make a new one